# Sampling from a Computed Multivariate kernel density estimation

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, kernel-density

Say I have X and Y coordinates on a map and a non-parametric distribution of "hot zones" (e.g. degree of pollution on a geographic map positioned at X and Y coordinates). My input data are heat maps.

I want to train a machine learning model that learns what a "hot zone" looks like, but I don't have a lot of labeled examples. All "hot zones" look pretty similar, but may be in different parts of my standardized XY coordinate map.

I can calculate a multivariate KDE and plot the density maps accordingly. To generate synthetic labeled data, can I "reverse" the KDE and randomly generate new image files with observations that fall within my KDE's "dense" range?

Is there any way to do this in python?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43674/simple-sampling-method-for-a-kernel-density-estimator

Answer (score 6):

There are at least 3 high-quality kernel-density estimation implementations available for python:

- [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)
- [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity)
- [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/nonparametric.html)

My personal ranking is **statsmodels > scikit-learn > scipy (best to worst)** but it will depend on your use-case.

Some random-remarks:

- scikit-learn offers sampling from a fitted KDE for free (`kde.sample(N)`)
- scikit-learn offers good cross-validation functions based on grid-search or random-search (cross-validation is highly recommended)
- statsmodels offers cross-validation methods based on optimization (can be slow for big datasets; but very high accuracy)

There are much more differences and some of these were analyzed in this very good [blog post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/) by *Jake VanderPlas*. The following table is an excerpt from this post:

[image: From: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/ (Jake VanderPlas)]
 <sup>*From: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/ (Author: Jake VanderPlas)*</sup>

#### Here is some example code using **scikit-learn**:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create test-data
data_x, data_y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, n_features=2, centers=7, cluster_std=0.5, random_state=0)

# Fit KDE (cross-validation used!)
params = {'bandwidth': np.logspace(-1, 2, 30)}
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(), params)
grid.fit(data_x)
kde = grid.best_estimator_
bandwidth = grid.best_params_['bandwidth']

# Resample
N_POINTS_RESAMPLE = 1000
resampled = kde.sample(N_POINTS_RESAMPLE)

# Plot original data vs. resampled
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i in range(100):
    axs[0,0].scatter(*data_x[i])
axs[0,1].hexbin(data_x[:, 0], data_x[:, 1], gridsize=20)

for i in range(N_POINTS_RESAMPLE):
    axs[1,0].scatter(*resampled[i])
axs[1,1].hexbin(resampled[:, 0], resampled[:, 1], gridsize=20)

plt.show()
```

#### Output:

[image]